# search string & cut in same awk command

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have file **abc.txt** which has data like -

```
abc pqr testing, xyz=a432j42jjk4, key=124

abc pqr testing, xyz=jkl234j54nn, key=567
abc pqr testing, xyz=2395hdshkw4, key=3232


abc pqr testing, xyz=abc424729hh, key=7676
abc pqr testing, xyz=70700ghgh99, key=12342
```

I am searching text "xyz" using awk like -

```
awk -F"xyz=" '{print $2}' abc.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

which gives me output with new lines in it -

```
a432j42jjk4,

jkl234j54nn,
2395hdshkw4,


abc424729hh,
70700ghgh99,
```

I am looking for shortcut or trick in awk where I can get output at the same time remove newlines from it.

Comment: The trick that you're looking for is to put NF as the pattern to match for either rule. For example, use `NF {print $2}` or `NF {print $1}` or both in your case. Placing NF makes sure that only non-blank lines/records are processed by the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GNU `grep` for it:

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<=\bxyz=)[^,]+,' abc.txt
```

`grep` prints lines that matches a given regular expression. With `-o` we define to print only the matching part of the line. With `-P` our regex is interpreted as a perl regex, which give us more option.

Our regex says:

- find one more characters that are not a `,` (`[^,]+`) and end with `,`
- these consecutive character should follow after a `xyz=` `(?<=\bxyz=)` this is called a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). With the `\b` we make sure not grep something like `booxyz=`

Comment: how this exactly works. can you please elaborate significance of each options & regex?

Comment: also this prints ) [^ along with the output. how I can ignore that?

Comment: a positive lookbehind to be more precise

Comment: `grep` doesn't add any additional character. So I don't understand what you mean by  "this prints ) [^ along with the output"?

Comment: Output was correct but first two lines were ) [^. I added sed '/^) /d' and removed

Comment: Note that this would also match `booxyz=` an similar strings (`xyz=` with any prefix), not just `xyz=`.  It would also match `xyz=` in the first comma-delimited field if there is one such string there, or in later fields for that matter, if the second field does not contain it.

Comment: You're right @Kusalananda. I've edited to match those cases correctly.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the built-in match capability of `awk` to streamline the command further:

```
$ awk -F ',' '/xyz=/ {split($2,a,"="); print a[2]}' file
a432j42jjk4
jkl234j54nn
2395hdshkw4
abc424729hh
70700ghgh99
```

Here we use `awk` to match lines that contain `xyz=`, so we don't have to use the `if` statement later to strip out the empty lines.

This looks more readable because the logic flows more from left to right.

This solution does not guard against the case where `xyz=` appears in a field other than the second in the comma-delimited file.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `awk` and assuming that you'd want to look for `xyz=` *specifically* in the second comma-delimited field.

```
$ awk -F ',' '{ split($2,a,"="); if (a[1] == " xyz") print a[2] }' file
a432j42jjk4
jkl234j54nn
2395hdshkw4
abc424729hh
70700ghgh99
```

Alternatively,

```
$ awk -F ',' '{ split($2,a,"=") } a[1] == " xyz" { print a[2] }' file
a432j42jjk4
jkl234j54nn
2395hdshkw4
abc424729hh
70700ghgh99
```

This would treat the input as consisting of lines with comma-delimited fields.  The actual body of the `awk` code will split the second comma-delimited field into subfields on `=`, and then print the second one of these if the first one is exactly the string `xyz` (including the initial space before the comma).

Empty lines would be dropped as `a[1]` would not get the wanted value on these lines.

Would you want extra commas at the end of each line of output, use `print a[2] ","`.